# Is there a feature or plugin to show include files inline with the top level .asp file for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-code, server-side-includes

**My question is:** Is there a feature in, or a plugin for, Visual Studio Code that would load and display the contents of the server-side-includes inline when editing an .asp file? I.e., is there a way to have VSCode build and display the page for editing in a similar way that IIS does when responding to an HTTP request?

**Why I'm asking:** At my place of work, our web pages are complicated messes of .asp files with server-side-includes (some of which have their own includes), some of which are out of our division's control. Some of these open HTML tags that we have to close in the top level .asp file. This makes editing and debugging these pages difficult. We can't use tag matching to tell if we've actually closed everything. A standard trick of ours is to just add closing `div` tags until it works. Changing how the pages are built is out of our control, it is the organization's way of enforcing a standard look and feel to the overall site.

Comment: I've found File Peek, which I think with settings changes might do it, but it's not working for me. But then, CSS Peek also doesn't work for me :\

Comment: CSS Peek now works for me (always did, I was using it wrong), so that's not related.